# Trying to evenly space out an image nav link with the rest of the text links in navigation

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make my first website after reading an html/css book.
I'm having difficulty evenly spacing out my navigation.
[image]

The image is vertically centered, however the text gets thrown off. Just need help in how to correct this.

html:

```
<nav>
<ul>
    <li><a style="padding: 0;" href="html.html">
        <img src="Images/Intak Mark-01.png" />
        </a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="html.html">Printing</a></li>
    <li><a href="html.html">Graphic Design</a></li>
    <li><a href="html.html">Chinese Calendars</a></li>
    <li><a href="html.html">FAQS</a></li>
    <li><a href="html.html">Contact Us</a></li>
</ul>
```

css:

```
    nav {
    position: fixed; left: 0px; top: 0px; 
    margin: 0; 
    background-color: black; 
    align-content: center; 
    font-size: 20px; 
    float: left; 
    border-radius: 0px;
    border: none;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}

ul {list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
}

li {display: block;
float: left;
padding: 15px 32px;
}

a {text-decoration: none; color: white;}
}
```

If there this is really bad markup, please let me know how I can fix it. I'm still learning.

Also had a separate question. The body I just repeated the word "text" to show how the scrolling would look. I tried using position: sticky, as I found a solution on line for having the text start at the bottom of the nav instead of underneath. However, when I do this, the nav no longer expands the entire width of the viewport.

Comment: Your markup is good. However, I just wonder if you forgot to close the `<nav>` tag or is just copy / paste error

Comment: I had it, but it wouldn’t appear in the code for some reason. It shows if I keep the </nav> next to the a }, but as soon as I press enter to show it below, it disappears. wasn’t sure if it was a bug, or a code limit or something

Comment: Ok ! Also noticed you have an extra `}` at the end of your css. Something to note is that in CSS nested rules `{{}}` never exists. Also, make sure you have an IDE that will highlight such errors ;)

Comment: I did, thanks :)I use dreamweaver

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
.nav {
    background: tomato;
    padding: 25px;
    display: flex;
    list-style: none;
    flex-direction: row;
    /* vertical alignement */
    align-items: center;
    /* how you want horizontal distribution */
    /* space-evenly | space-around | space-between */
    justify-content: space-evenly;
}

.item {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

.item:first-child {
    height: 50px;
    line-height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<ul class="nav">
    <li class="item">navA</li>
    <li class="item">navB</li>
    <li class="item">my third item</li>
    <li class="item">Blah</li>
    <li class="item">Contact</li>
</ul>
```

Flexbox layouts ar the way to go now.

Example for your case:

```css
nav > ul {
    background: tomato;
    padding: 25px;
    display: flex;
    list-style: none;
    flex-direction: row;
    /* vertical alignement */
    align-items: center;
    /* how you want horizontal distribution */
    /* space-evenly | space-around | space-between */
    justify-content: space-evenly;
}
```

**Alternative**

If you look closely at the CSS in the code snippet, you can see I used another trick to vertically center text inside a div, is to use line-height. For example, if you know your image is gonna be 50px height and your nav link will not take two lines, you can put `line-height: 50px`

Comment: I noticed you used .nav {} instead of nav {}. Is there a reason to keep all CSS in classes and not apply to entire elements?

Comment: It depends on how much elements you get on the page. My rule of thumb is: use `#id` if style apply to only one element (that is what I should have used), use `.class` if your style apply OR may apply to many elements and use `element` if you want a global style...but in your case, if you are sure to use `nav` only once, you can use `nav` has a selector

Comment: Also could you provide a code example (codepen or so) for your second question ? I don't understand clearly your demand

Comment: The position:flex fixes the text starting at the top of the viewport and not the below the navigation.

Comment: It doesn't seem I can attach images to comments, but adding the code you provided, everything is fixed, however, I can't get rid of a margin gap to the left of the nav bar. I have margin: 0, and position: flex; top: 0; left: 0;. However, when I change position: fixed, the bar locks to the top left, but all the spacing is erased

Comment: One of the default CSS rule is a margin on the body. Try to add `html, body {margin:0;}` to your css

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190084/discussion-between-538romeo-and-yabusa).